# Does the EU release of Pokemon Black / White work in a NA DSi?

Tags: pokemon-series, region-lock, nintendo-dsi

[The Japanese version of Pokemon Black & White does not work on North American DSi systems.](http://www.siliconera.com/2010/09/17/pokemon-black-white-are-region-locked-on-nintendo-dsi/)

But [But the Australian version of it works on a Japanese 3DS.](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/topic/27593125/pokemon-black-and-white-is-region-free-)

Does anyone know if the European cartridge will work on a North American DSi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  ([Source](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?s=9a2501ec8ba50d10c349189265f44a59&p=26286971&postcount=48))

Note that EU/AU is the same region ([1](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?s=9a2501ec8ba50d10c349189265f44a59&p=26221139&postcount=27), [2](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?s=9a2501ec8ba50d10c349189265f44a59&p=26221145&postcount=28)).  So in fact, you answered your own question with the link that says the AU version is not locked :P